# How to use switch statement inside for loop?

Tags: javascript

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  if(i%3===0) {
   console.log(i, 'Foo')
  } else {
   console.log(i, 'Default')
  }
}
```

Now, I wonder how can we write the code using switch statement inside the loop:

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  switch(i) {
   case (i%3===0):
    console.log(i,'Foo')
    break
   default:
    console.log(i,'Default')
    break
  }
}
```

But it results 'Default' always. I have tried using label, anonymous function, etc. but not able to output like if condition. Am I doing something wrong with the switch statment?

**Edit:**

I was trying to do like this in fact:

```
case (i%3===0):
   console.log(i,'Foo')
   break
case (i%5===0):
   console.log(i,'Bar')
   break
```

Comment: Yes, you've got the `i%3` in the wrong place.

Comment: @Pointy Can you please provide me answer looking at the Edit.

Comment: A `switch` statement is not appropriate in that situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to use a `switch` statement like a series of `if` and `else if` statements. A switch statement does not work that way. The first case that matches the value of the variable that is in the switch statement will be evaluated. You can use `switch(true)` so the first case that is true will be evaluated.

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  switch(true) {
   case (i%3===0)://if
    console.log(i,'Foo')
    break
   case (i%5===0)://else if
     console.log(i,'Bar')
     break
   default://else
    console.log(i,'Default')
    break
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to switch the value of `i` modulo `3` (if it equals zero then it is divisible by `3`).

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  switch(i%3) {
   case (0):
    console.log(i,'Foo')
    break
   default:
    console.log(i,'Default')
    break
  }
}
```

However, a `switch` statement generally should not be used in this case. You should just go with a series of `if` (and `else if` statements).

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  if(i%3==0){
    console.log(i, 'Foo');
  } else if(i%5==0){
    console.log(i, 'Bar');
  } else {
    console.log(i, 'Default');
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @ukri No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the value of `i%3` in a variable and use that in `switch-case` because the `case` evaluates a constant or expression.

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  var val = i%3;
  switch(val) {
   case 0:
    console.log(i,'Foo')
    break;
   default:
    console.log(i,'Default')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this - with the %3 moved

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  switch(i%3) {
   case 0:
    console.log(i,'Foo')
    break;
   default:
    console.log(i,'Default')
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch the expression you want to check against, in this case that's `i%3` and than make cases for what that expression might be, e.g. `case 0:`, `case 1:` and so on:

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  switch(i%3) {
   case 0:
    console.log(i,'Foo')
    break;
   case 1:
    console.log(i,'Bar')
   default:
    console.log(i,'Default')
  }
}
```